# MYSQL - Finding distinct records and sort by another field length

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, distinct

First, thank you everyone for taking the time to help with my issue.

I have a table which consists of `id` and `content`

An example set of data is:

```
id  content
9   With astonishing insight and poignant precision
8   Whether they find themselves hacking rattles from the tails of snakes or nesting rattles in the hands of their babies.
4   This is a clear-eyed, deeply poignant collection.
12  This book is a dynamic compilation of snapshot tales, each of which encompasses its own sensory-rich world and can be read.
12  This book is an appropriate title for her collection-the prose poems feel revealed.
12  This book is a collection of ekphrastic vignettes set against surreal backdrops fraught with eerie characters faking normalcy.
```

What I need to do is find the shortest length `content` for each unique `id`

For example, the output of the above should be:

```
id  content
9   With astonishing insight and poignant precision
8   Whether they find themselves hacking rattles from the tails of snakes or nesting rattles in the hands of their babies.
4   This is a clear-eyed, deeply poignant collection.
12  This book is an appropriate title for her collection-the prose poems feel revealed.
```

What I have so far, and is obviously wrong is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, content FROM t
    GROUP BY id;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to calculate the shortest length and then join the results back in:

```
select t.id, t.content
from (select id, min(length(content)) as minl
      from t
      group by id
     ) tmin join
     t
     on t.id = tmin.id and length(t.content) = tmin.minl;
```

Note:  if two contents have the same length and are the minimum, this will return both of them.  Your question doesn't specify what to do in this case.

Comment: Gordon, thanks!  I'm not overly concerned if they are the same length.  I'm more interested in making sure I present content that isn't too long for my intentions, not the specific content element itself.

Comment: @amac . . . You could choose an arbitrary `content` and just use `left()` to get the first "n" characters.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, however, I need to display the full value of the `content` field, and not a truncated field value.